# Change Data- MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In the "Summary View" of the Auditing , I understand that all the records has their fields with corresponding old and new value. In the back end (Audit table ) it is stored in the form of Attribute Mask and Change Data. As far  I understood , attribute mask refers to the column identity ( Correct me if I am wrong ) . I am not quite clear about format in which the values are stored in the Change Data column .

Any leads on this?

Humble thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears from the Audit Trails, both the Attribute Mask and Change Data are stored as string. On further inspection into the database, if you look into the "AuditBase" table, you'll find that the Change Data is of type nvarchar(max).

EDIT : You can try out the steps mentioned here to decrypt the Attribute Maske column - http://kelvinshen.blogspot.in/2012_02_01_archive.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am interested in knowing how it is stored  and how to decrypt it.

Comment: I need to unpack the change data

Comment: If you mean de-masking the Attribute Mask, see my edited answer above to find the link on how to achieve that.